Transforming a sorted array into a maximally unsorted circular buffer
If I have a sorted array, e.g.
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']

Is there an algorithm for turning this into:
['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B']

i.e. One of the maximally unsorted permutations, when considered as a circular buffer.
There may be many maximally unsorted permutations; many will be rotations or mirrors of each other.
The "circular buffer" restriction means that the first and last positions should be considered adjacent, like any other two neighbours.
The "unsortedness" is the sum of the reciprocals of the (circular) offsets between identical elements.
For the sorted list, far above:
A: 1 + 1 + 1/8                 ==  2 1/8
B: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1/5     ==  5 1/5
C: 1 + 1/9                     ==  1 1/9
                                  -------
                  unsortedness ==  7.436

For the unsorted list, above:
A: 1/4 + 1/2 + 1/4             ==  1
B: 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 ==  2 1/2
C: 1/6 + 1/4                   ==    5/12      
                                  -------
                  unsortedness ==  3.917


Have you tried a greedy method?

How large are your arrays in practice?

This sounds like the problem of evenly distributing items in a list. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37452547/56778 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29709/8314

@D.W. They are 100 items or less, and the process only needs to happen once.  Any sane amount of big-O complexity will be fine @ 3GHz.

Got it, thank you.  How many unique items do you expect to have?  Also do you need the exact optimum or would you be satisfied with an algorithm that usually yields a solution that is fairly close to optimal?

@D.W. Fairly close to optimal would be fine, but it should be optimal for simple cases. i.e. the example above should never have two adjacent Bs. Up to 16 unique items.
